# Concatenar linhas em apenas uma

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, case

Boa tarde, preciso unificar alguns dados, quando eu trago esta assim:

```
id 2017 2017-LOJA   2018    2018-LOJA
1   n       n        s          s
1   s       s       n           n
```

Gostaria assim:

```
id 2017 2017-LOJA   2018    2018-LOJA
1   s       s        s          s
```

consulta que fiz:

```
SELECT id, 
CASE WHEN YEAR(DATA) = 2017 THEN 'S' END AS '2017',
CASE WHEN YEAR(DATA) = 2017 AND ORIGEM = 'LOJA' THEN 'S' END AS '2017 - LOJA',
CASE WHEN YEAR(DATA) = 2018 THEN 'S' END AS '2018',
CASE WHEN YEAR(DATA) = 2018 AND ORIGEM = 'LOJA' THEN 'S' END AS '2018 - LOJA'
FROM table
WHERE ORIGEM = 'LOJA'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente

```
SELECT id, 
       max (CASE WHEN YEAR(DATA) = 2017 THEN 'S' END) AS [2017],
       max (CASE WHEN YEAR(DATA) = 2017 AND ORIGEM = 'LOJA' THEN 'S' END) AS [2017 - LOJA],
       max (CASE WHEN YEAR(DATA) = 2018 THEN 'S' END) AS [2018],
       max (CASE WHEN YEAR(DATA) = 2018 AND ORIGEM = 'LOJA' THEN 'S' END) AS [2018 - LOJA]
  FROM table
  WHERE ORIGEM = 'LOJA'  
  group by id;
```